# PHP variable return on function

Tags: php

Hello I have my php code, a function and basically I want to return a variable. Here is the code:

```
<?php       
function GetWebsiteName(){
    $sql = "SELECT website_name FROM configuration";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $GetWebsiteName = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    return $GetWebsiteName;
}
?>
```

How can I return my variable?

Comment: Establish a connection?  What makes you think you aren't returning it already?  What error do you get?

Comment: Is not returning the value.

Comment: You need to elaborate your question..are you mistaking return with outputting to the browser? Is what you want `var_dump(GetWebsiteName());`?

Comment: basically I want to <? write $sitename ?>

Comment: Then do `<?php var_dump(GetWebsiteName()); ?>`.

Comment: Not exactly. It should be `<?php echo GetWebsiteName()['website_name']; ?>` or change `return $GetWebsiteName;` to `return $GetWebsiteName['website_name'];`

Comment: @sjagr Correct. This seemed like a way to elaborate on what's going on later when we get some output :).

Comment: Do you think you can write the code?

Comment: @user3263967 Only if you plan on paying me to do your work for you

Comment: @user3263967 But advice is free...

Comment: Haha how much are you charging?

Answer (score 1):

mysql_fetch_assoc() returns an array not a string, even if you only select one column in the query.

This should work:

```
$result_array = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
return $result_array['website_name'];
```

Check the docs for clarification: https://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc

(Please note the large red box on the docs page. Consider migrating ALL your mysql functions to mysqli or PDO)

Comment: Yea no its not working do you think you can post the whole code?

Comment: My response only addresses the primary question you posted of how to return the value from the function properly. You could potentially have other errors, such as a bad database connection or a failed query. Unless you are testing for such cases and displaying error messages when they happen it's nearly impossible to figure out why your function doesn't work as expected. Please look into how to test for these potential errors and how to display them.